# a month later / a month after now / a month from now

Tags: sentence-construction

I’m currently doing a job of designing a website for the competition that I’m currently participating in. Given that I’m majoring in architecture engineering, which I think is totally different from what I’m currently doing, everything is so new to me that I can’t figure out anything at once. As the time when I have to submit the final things, I feel obliged to do my best. I don't have enough time to do this slowly.

> 1. It's about a month later that I have to submit.

I think it is acceptable. And how about these?

> 2. It's about a month from now that I have to submit.
> 3. It's about a month after now that I have to submit.

Comment: for time you'd better use *when*, *it's about a month later when I have to submit the project*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I did not fully understand your question, from the 'quoted sentences', I think you are trying to say that you have one month to submit whatsoever the project you are working on. If that's the case, it's simple...

> I have (got) one month to submit the project.

---

When it comes to submit an important project, I would prefer telling the date precisely because such dates are 'fixed'.

Say...

> The deadline of submitting this projects is September 6

Answer (score 0):

You may say

> I have to submit the project within the next month (means less than a month)

You'd better use the time in the end of your sentences as I did, but if you want to keep your style, you'd better use "when", I prefer

> One month from now is when I have to submit the project
>
> One month later, I have to submit the project